# IONIC ignore network_security_config.xml because wanted to get data from different server

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, android-security, android-network-security-config, ionicsecurity

I have somewhat wired requirement,

I have developed one mobile application that I will be delivered to different customers. And that app will exchange data with the customer local server.

But in this, while creating the APK build we are hardcoding domain/IP in network_security_config.xml as android provided extra security after Android 7 onwards.

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.162</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Question:

**How to configure the dynamic IP address in this config file so it will allow me to exchange the data from different servers at runtime.**

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure - I work for Ionic Security, which was flagged here. But I believe you can add multiple domains in your config (see: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) or remove those and rely on trusting their certs.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Floyd, but on compile-time, we don't know which IP address we are building this APK for.